# Cannot invoke "org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.getStringCellValue()" because the return value of org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.getCell(int) is null

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am accessing my Excel sheet data and I am able to get my output but along with that am getting an error:

> Cannot invoke "org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.getStringCellValue()" because the return value of org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.getCell(int) is null

I get this error on this line of code:

```
if(r.getCell(column).getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Login ID")
```

This is my whole code:

```
package Exceltwo.guruExcel;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class excelDataProvider {

//Identify Testcases column by scanning the entire 1st row
//once column is identified then scan entire testcase column to identify purchase testcase row
//after you grab purchase testcase row = pull all the data of that row and feed into test

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\mimo\\Desktop\\workbookexample.xlsx");
    XSSFWorkbook workbook=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

    int sheets = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();

    for (int i = 0; i < sheets; i++)
    {
        if (workbook.getSheetName(i).equalsIgnoreCase("Sheet1"))
        {
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
            //Identify Testcases column by scanning the entire 1st row
            Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.iterator();  // sheet is collection of rows
            Row firstrow = rows.next();

            Iterator<Cell> ce = firstrow.cellIterator();  // row is collection of cells
            int k = 0;
            int column = 0;

            while (ce.hasNext())
            {
                 Cell value = ce.next();
 
                 if (value.getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Testcase"))
                 {
                     column = k;
                 }

                 k++;
             }

             System.out.println(column);

             // once column is identified then scan entire testcase column to identify purchase testcase row
             while (rows.hasNext())
             {
                 Row r = rows.next();

                 if (r.getCell(column).getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Login ID"))
                 { 
                     // after you grab purchase testcase row = pull all the data of that row and feed into test
                     Iterator<Cell> cv = r.cellIterator();

                     while (cv.hasNext())
                     {
                          Cell c = cv.next();
                          System.out.println(c);
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

[Excel Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrGlp.png)

[Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tv0Lw.png)

Comment: Check if that cell exists before you look at the contents? If the cell is empty and has never been used, it won't be in the file so you'll get a `null` when you fetch it!

Comment: What is the cell value you are trying to get?

Comment: @Gagravarr I have attached a screenshot of my excel sheet for your reference. What am trying to do in this program is first am searching for a value (Login ID) in a row. Once my value is matched then am iterating through each and every cell of that row.

Comment: @itronic1990 I am first searching for Testcase name if it matches to login ID, I want to fetch all the cell values corresponding to login ID in my excel sheet.

Comment: What @Gagravarr tried to say is that `Row.getCell` may return null. So `if(r.getCell(coloumn).getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Login ID"))` is very bad practice and screams for `NPE`. As a one liner it would must be `if(r.getCell(coloumn)!=null && r.getCell(coloumn).getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Login ID"))`. But such one liners also are bad practice. So get the cell first. Then check whether it is not `null`. Then check whether it has a string cell value. Then get the cell value. Then check whether it equals "Login ID".

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments `r.getCell(column)` can return null.

Another option (besides checking for null) is to use `CellUtil.getCell(r, column)` which will not return null, as it will create the cell if it doesn't exist.

See https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellUtil.html#getCell-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row-int-

Answer (score 1):

```
    **Add one more if block for checking whether the cell is null or not then it will execute without any error...**

while(rows.hasNext())
{
    Row r=rows.next();
    if(r.getCell(column)!=null)
    {                    
       if(r.getCell(column).getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Login ID"))
       {
          Iterator<Cell> cv=r.cellIterator();
          while(cv.hasNext())
          {
                Cell c = cv.next();
                System.out.println(c);
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```java
while (cv.hasNext())
```

to this

```java
while (cv.hasNext() == true)
```

It because, there is no available value after the next / down cells of the given cell.